# PHP and date formatting in access mdb

Tags: php, date, ms-access, pdo

I'm using PHP to insert data to an MS Access DB (*.mdb).
The field CreateDate is of type Date/Time and the data that gets inserted is in the wrong format. This is my query:

```
$date = date('d/m/Y');
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Dbq="mydb.mdb"; Uid=Admin");     
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO Cup_Package (Cup_BorgPartnerID, Name, CreateDate)           VALUES (1, 'Catalog and Price Update', $date)");
```

but instead of writing a date like 2/9/2013, the date field gets 30/12/1899 which probably means either that the formatting i'm giving is incorrect or that the date field is getting no data at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Access, date literals must be enclosed in `#` and are formatted as such:

```
#MM/DD/YYYY#
```

or, for a Date and Time:

```
#MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS#
```

Access also accept date literals as decimal numbers where the integer part is the number of days and the decimal part is the fraction of a day.

In your case though:

```
$date = date('m/d/Y');
$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO Cup_Package (Cup_BorgPartnerID, Name, CreateDate) 
           VALUES (1, 'Catalog and Price Update', #$date#)");
```

Comment: But `$date` is a string in *'d/m/Y'* format.  The db engine expects date literals in *'m/d/Y'* format regardless of locale, or *Y-m-d*.

Comment: @HansUp: Good catch, I hadn't paid enough attention to the existing format string, I thought it was OK and that only the `#` were missing. Thanks!